# Spanish location for yii2-date-picker-widget

Tags: datepicker, yii2

I am working on the basic template of Yii2. I use the [2amigos yii2-date-picker-widget](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-date-picker-widget).
Datepicker is working fine, but it keeps showing me the default language (that is English) instead of Spanish.
As you can see in the code below, the language param is set to 'es':

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'alta')->widget(
    DatePicker::className(), [
        'inline' => false, 
        'clientOptions' => [
            'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            'weekStart' => 1,
            'todayBtn' => 'linked',
            'clearBtn' => true,
            'language' => 'es',
            'autoclose' => true,
            'todayHighlight' => true
        ]
]);?>
```

It seems tha the 2amigos Datepicker comes into the proper location whith:

```
DatePickerLanguageAsset::register($view)->js[] = 'bootstrap-datepicker.' . $this->language . '.min.js';
```

that means @vendor/bower/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.es.min.js, that is an existing file containing my desired spanish location:

```
!function(a){a.fn.datepicker.dates.es={days:["Domingo","Lunes","Martes","Miércoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sábado","Domingo"],daysShort:["Dom","Lun","Mar","Mié","Jue","Vie","Sáb","Dom"],daysMin:["Do","Lu","Ma","Mi","Ju","Vi","Sa","Do"],months:["Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre"],monthsShort:["Ene","Feb","Mar","Abr","May","Jun","Jul","Ago","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dic"],today:"Hoy",clear:"Borrar",weekStart:1,format:"dd/mm/yyyy"}}(jQuery);
```

Why this translation is not being applied?
A lot of thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your translation doesn't work because of wrong syntax, You should move Your language param from 'clientOptions' to top level array:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'alta')->widget(
DatePicker::className(), [
    'inline' => false, 
    'language' => 'es',
    'clientOptions' => [
        'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        'weekStart' => 1,
        'todayBtn' => 'linked',
        'clearBtn' => true,
        'autoclose' => true,
        'todayHighlight' => true
        ]
]);?>
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you very much user2687375.